# Launching localhost website in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0

Up until now, I've been using a local DNS tool to remap my domain to a local IP address, so that when I test my website in the browser, I just enter www.mysite.com. Due to some testing for Google OAuth code, it seems I need to have my site run as `http://localhost:8080` but all the sample's I've seen uses something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/sample
```

But this is designed to work with Visual Studio's own webserver and not IIS. How can I access my site from IIS using localhost?

Comment: set virtual path to `/sample` under project properties > web

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use you local IIS server as Web Server instead of Visual Studio Developer Server. Please refer image and change settings try it.[image]